# Amazon DynamoDB putItem returning null

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-java-sdk

I am using AmazonDynamoDBClient putItem method to insert item in DB. return type of putItem is PutItemResult but i m getting it as null.

```
AmazonDynamoDBClient client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient();
PutItemRequest r = new PutItemRequest();
r.addItemEntry("custId",new Attribute Value("101"));
PutItemResult result = client.putItem(r);
//result is null
```

Item is inserted successfully in DB but why result is getting as null?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please specify the **RETURN_VALUE** based on your requirement. The default is **NONE**.

> ReturnValues — (String) Use ReturnValues if you want to get the item
>   attributes as they appeared before they were updated with the PutItem
>   request. For PutItem, the valid values are:
>
> NONE - If ReturnValues is not specified, or if its value is NONE, then
>   nothing is returned. (This setting is the default for ReturnValues.)
>   ALL_OLD - If PutItem overwrote an attribute name-value pair, then the
>   content of the old item is returned. Note: The ReturnValues parameter
>   is used by several DynamoDB operations; however, PutItem does not
>   recognize any values other than NONE or ALL_OLD.

**From API docs:-**

```
public PutItemRequest(String tableName,
                      Map<String,AttributeValue> item,
                      String returnValues)
```

[Set return values](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/model/PutItemRequest.html#setReturnValues-com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.ReturnValue-)

> The ReturnValues parameter is used by several DynamoDB operations;
>   however, PutItem does not recognize any values other than NONE or
>   ALL_OLD.

ALL_NEW, UPDATED_NEW and UPDATED_OLD are for UpdateItem operations.

> UPDATED_OLD - Returns only the updated attributes, as they appeared
>   before the UpdateItem operation.
>
> ALL_NEW - Returns all of the attributes of the item, as they appear
>   after the UpdateItem operation.
>
> UPDATED_NEW - Returns only the updated attributes, as they appear
>   after the UpdateItem operation.

Comment: PutItem does not recognize any values other than NONE or ALL_OLD then why there is ALL_NEW and other ReturnValues present? What if i inserted a item first time and wants to return the same item ?

Comment: Updated the answer for other return values. They are specifically for update item.

Comment: got it . Thanks!